# Scan a single channel to measure RSSI of a specific AP when not associated

Tags: wi-fi

I would like to (repeatedly) measure the RSSI of a given Wi-Fi access point while I am (physically) approaching it. It is important to mention that at the beginning, my phone is not associated with the AP, hence reading RSSI via `wpa_cli signal_poll` does not work.

The best I have found so far is to repeatedly issue a `wpa_cli scan` and read the results using `wpa_cli bss <BSSID>`. However, this gives me new results with much too low frequency, as the scans take too much time. I target to get a new RSSI every second. (even if I limit scanning to the 5GHz band only, it is too slow).

Is there any way to scan for a single channel only (as I know the channel the access point is transmitting on)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install `iw` and then issue:

```
iw dev wlan0 scan freq 2417
```

It synchronously scans only the frequency(ies) you specify. This can give you multiple results per second!

Answer (score 0):

If using the shell isn't a problem, you can compile `iwlist` command for ARM, and transfer it to device. `iwlist scan` as root may give you better results.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `iwlist scan` does indeed give sufficiently verbose results. However, it still suffers from the fact that it issues a scan and exactly that scan takes too much time. I need another way to monitor RSSI than scanning repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily have to use shell for this. Try out [inSSIDer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.metageek&feature=nav_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDMsIm5ldC5tZXRhZ2VlayJd) it provides RSSI data, but I am not sure how realtime this data is.

For me this app is used to verify the consistency of the AP's (Enterprise network) in a certain location and their typical radio switch zone.

Comment: This is indeed a nice app, but unfortunately I need to log RSSI over time which this app seems to be unable to do.